# How to check type of object in VB 6 - Is there any method other than 'TypeName'

Tags: vb6

How to check type of object in VB 6 - Is there any method other than 'TypeName' because its not feasible to check it witrh 'TypeName' I am expecting something like QuichWatch window.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For object variables, use `TypeOf ... Is`:

```
If TypeOf VarName Is TypeName Then
  ''# ...
End If
```

For example:

```
Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject

If TypeOf fso Is Scripting.FileSystemObject Then
  Debug.Print "Yay!"
End If
```

Answer (score 7):

Just to add to @Tomalak's answer... If the object variable has not been instantiated then testing with TypeOf will cause a run time error. Also note the class may implement interfaces e.g.

```
Dim fs As Scripting.FileSystemObject

On Error Goto Err_Handler

If TypeOf fs Is Scripting.FileSystemObject Then
  Debug.Print "[Won't get here]"
End If

Err_Handler:

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  Debug.Print "Oops, error when fs Is Nothing"
End If

On Error Resume Next

Set fs = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

If TypeOf fs Is Scripting.FileSystemObject Then
  Debug.Print "Is a FileSystemObject"
End If

If TypeOf fs Is IFileSystem Then
  Debug.Print "Implements IFileSystem "
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one.

```
dim obj as object
for each obj in me
   debug.print TypeName(obj)
next
```

Comment: Thanks, but do check type of object we have to modify existing code is there any method like moving cursor orer it or like quick watch where I can see its type