# How to check type of Object in VB 6 ? - I do not want to use 'TypeOf' method

Tags: vb.net, variables, types, vb6

How to check type of object in VB 6.0 we have to modify existing code to use 'typeof' method, Is there any method like moving cursor over object variable or like quick watch where I can see its type.

I know following method but I do not want to use it -

```
Set fs = New Scripting.FileSystemObject 

If TypeOf fs Is Scripting.FileSystemObject Then 
  Debug.Print "Is a FileSystemObject" 
End If
```

Comment: You shouldn't be having a problem with "Add Watch" and "Quick Watch". These two debug windows should show the data-type.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try the [TypeName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263394(v=VS.60).aspx) Function.

In your example if you enter `TypeName(fs)` in the Immediate Window you would get back "FileSystemObject"

Comment: +1 I took the liberty of editing your answer to add a link to the VB6 manual topic for `TypeName`

Comment: The original question was, "How to check type of object... other than 'TypeName'" !! (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684693/how-to-check-type-of-object-in-vb-6-is-there-any-method-other-than-typename)

Answer (score 0):

Right click object variable and select "Quick Info" from context menu.