# How to determine the type of control (or object)?

Tags: vba, vb6

There are three only ways, which are discussed on the Internet and on this forum in particular
*[How to check type of object in VB 6 - Is there any method other than 'TypeName'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684693/how-to-check-type-of-object-in-vb-6-is-there-any-method-other-than-typename?s=1|2.2690)

[How to check type of Object in VB 6 ? - I do not want to use 'TypeOf' method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766898/how-to-check-type-of-object-in-vb-6-i-do-not-want-to-use-typeof-method?s=2|2.2284)

[How to check type of object in VB 6 - Is there any method other than 'TypeName'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684693/how-to-check-type-of-object-in-vb-6-is-there-any-method-other-than-typename)*

Namely:
- the string method `TypeName`
- the clumsy `TypeOf`
- by name of control, defined in a specific notation

Am I right, that **there are no built-in tools to get a normal numeric constant**, like the `MsoControlType`?
.

Comment: What is the use case? Are you referring to ActiveX controls, or VBA document hosted controls (i.e. ***not*** `MsoControlType.msoControlActiveX`). Do you consider the Windows APIs "built-in tools"?

Comment: @Comintern Rotfront! I mean "built-in" as without any special tweaks like special formed control name, third party tools etc., keeping my VB6 project with default references. In my today case I am dealing with a standard controls (CommandButton, CheckBox etc.) on the usual VB6 form...

Comment: I think this would be problematic to differentiate between controls. As the enumeration values overlap (e.g. usually the default is 1,2,3...) would that be problematic for what you are trying to do? You could make your own `Enum` if you like.

Comment: Do you consider the Windows APIs "keeping my VB6 project with default references"?

Comment: @RyanWildry Agree. But my today case is a simple and I am quite of `Select Case TypeName`. However, it's not very nice to roll strings instead of numbers :(

Comment: Enum's can return numeric values.

Comment: @Comintern You are ready to propose something from API? There must be a good reasons for such nonsense, to declare something else also ...

Comment: @RyanWildry Enum, API - all this are the third tools. Even the special naming too. Realy we have only two built-in methods. Thanks for M$ and on it.

Comment: Custom enums are part of VBA. They aren't third party.

Comment: You can *get* a unique number using the ole32.dll APIs (which are pretty much integral to VB6 anyway, so "external" is mainly semantics).  VB doesn't *need anything* other than the parent dll and the class string to retrieve the CLSID or ProgID. Those are the only 2 identifiers that COM cares about.  It doesn't even care about the CoClass for anything other than locating the IClassFactory interface - all it cares about are interfaces. An enum of CoClasses is an implementation detail of the ***library***. comctl32.dll isn't part of VB6, so why expect VB6 to provide the enumeration?

Comment: @RyanWildry _"They aren't third party"_ Sure? Listen to yourself - **_"Custom"_**. One form, one control, one line of code: `? Form.Control.Type` - this is not third party only, but native and built-in. If it were...

Comment: I guess we have different definitions of third party. Third party to me, means including code that is separate from what's already included with VBA. Here's how to use the Enum variable type if anyone is interested. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Enums.htm

Comment: How is `TypeOf` clumsy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Direct answer

> *Am I right, that there are no built-in tools to get a normal numeric constant, like the MsoControlType?*

Yes, that is correct. Unless you implement your own, using the techniques you've listed.

Well, excluding `VarType`, which will return `vbObject` given any object reference.

---

#### Pedantic answer

What you're referring to as a "normal numeric constant" has strictly nothing to do with a control's *type* - these `MsoControlType` constants are just `Enum` values that the `CommandBar` API uses to determine the *type* of the control to create when you ask to create one.

`MsoControlType.msoControlButton` is not a *type of control*, it's a constant with a value of 1. Nothing more, nothing less - the *type* of a control is a class, not a numeric constant:

```
?TypeName(Application.VBE.CommandBars(1).Controls(1))
CommandBarPopup
```

`CommandBarPopup` is the class (and thus the type of the control), not `msoControlPopup`, and not `10`:

[image: CommandBarPopup in the object browser]

A *type* is what you give to `TypeOf [variable] Is [*type*]`, or `Dim [variable] As [*type*]`: it's an identifier that refers to a class/interface (in the case of an object, of course - a *type* could also be one of the primitives, e.g. `Integer` or `Boolean`). And given the weakness of reflection capabilities in VB6/VBA for lack of a .net-like type system where a *type* itself is an abstraction that can be worked with, a custom `Enum` type and a function taking an object, featuring a `Select Case` block with `TypeOf` checks, is your best bet for that function to return a *normal numeric constant* that **represents** the type of the provided object.

Comment: It's worth noting that this abstraction is a *feature*, as it allows the implementation and even the class of the controls to vary *behind the scenes*. Also note that a `MsoControlType.msoControlActiveX` control actually stores its ClassInfo inside the FRX file (in the `ClassTable` in the `f` stream), so VBA always knows how to persist and restore the control.

Comment: @Mat's Mug Thanks a lot for short & clear answer and more thanks for detail & useful explain of problem.