# Check if Variable Type is a User-Defined Class with VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check type of object in VB 6 - Is there any method other than 'TypeName'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684693/how-to-check-type-of-object-in-vb-6-is-there-any-method-other-than-typename)

I have an object that I need to check if it is a certain user-defined class or not with something like the following code:

```
If Collection.Items(1).object = class1 then
 do something
end if
```

I'm not sure what the syntax is to perform evaluation of user-defined classes.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3684693/190829

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub tester()
    Dim o As New Class1
    Debug.Print TypeName(o)  ' "Class1"
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not perfect: two different classes can yield the same result, I think.  In any case, [TypeOf ... Is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4zz68xc.aspx) is faster.

Comment: @reinierpost - you are linking to the VB.NET docs for TypeOf

Comment: Good point. I can't find any VBA documentation.  It does work as described there.  There is VB6 documentation, which doesn't list `TypeOf`.