# Compare an Object to see if it is a Collection without using TypeName and comparing it as a String?

Tags: arrays, object, collections, vb6, compare

[The following is in VB6, and I have an Array of Collections that I would like to test to ensure something is of Type Collection]

I've looked at some code I've written years ago, and I'm doing the following to see if it is a Collection or not:

```
If TypeName(obj) = "Collection" Then ' Makes me feel uncomfortable.
```

But, I don't like the idea of doing String comparison (according to MSDN, degrades performance as well as making me feel uncomfortable) and would prefer to do something like this:

```
If obj Is Collection Then
```

However, this line produces a runtime error in VB6 stating that "Compiler error: variable not defined". Obviously, because the "Is" operator compares the value and not the type, so doing this will not produce a runtime error, but will always return False no matter what (even if I Set obj = New Collection right before):

```
Dim obj As Collection
Set obj = New Collection
If obj Is New Collection Then ' Returns False under every condition.
```

This is because "New Collection" will always be a new instance, and therefore a new location in memory (even if the value is the same).

Of course, I can (and do) use the following, but am after something more specific than just testing for Nothing:

```
If Not obj Is Nothing Then ' We can just assume it is a Collection Type.
```

But, I am looking at finding a better way to test if something is of a Collection Type, without just assuming it must be if it is not Nothing.

Thanks for your anticipated assistance.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684693/how-to-check-type-of-object-in-vb-6-is-there-any-method-other-than-typename

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `TypeOf`. For example:

`If  TypeOf obj Is Collection Then`

`TypeOf` is described in the `If ... Then ... Else' [topic in the VB6 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243382%28v=vs.60%29.aspx). *Thanks to Deanna for pointing this out!*

Comment: Ah, thanks mark, I tried typeof but in the wrong order and out of syntax. This is perfect. Accepted & up voted.