# VBA - Reference an object by using a variable

Tags: vba, excel

Not sure how to reference the worksheet object with a variable that changes each time a sheet is activated.

The point is to reference a cell value based on the last worksheet that was activated (this code affects Sheet1 which does not set the variable when activated)

```
--Module1
  Public MyWS as String

--Sheet3 (Deactivation)
  MyWS = Sheet3.Codename

--Sheet2 (Deactivation)
  MyWS = Sheet2.Codename

--Sheet1
  Sheet1.Range("A3").Value = MyWS.Range("A3").Value
```

**Updated:**

Thanks for all the guidance but your instructions are not working for my project at least.

Sheet5.Range("C4").Value = Worksheets(MyWS).Range("A2").Value

Subscript out of range error when the above code is executed on Sheet5 deactivate.

MyWS is declared as a public string.
MyWS is assigned the Sheet5.CodeName string when Sheet5 is activated. Sheet5 exists and that is the unmodified codename of the sheet. I can not use the user defined name of the sheet because that can change.

Comment: With Activesheet?

Comment: --Module1
  Public MyWS as Worksheet
--Sheet3 (Deactivate)
  Set MyWS = Activesheet
--Sheet2 (Deactivate)
  Set MyWS = ActiveSheet
--Sheet1
  Sheet1.Range("A3").Value = MyWS.Range("A3").Value

Doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: If this is VBA then why have to tagged it VB.NET?  Also, if you need to post code after the fact then edit your question.  As you can see, it's barely readable in a comment, especially if not formatted at all.

Answer (score 2):

`Public MyWS As String` declares a `String` variable, not an object.

#### CodeName

The `CodeName` property returns a `String` that contains an identifier that VBA uses to generate a project-scoped object variable for a `Worksheet`; in the *properties* toolwindow (F4), that's the `(Name)` property.

This is how such code is legal:

```
Sheet1.Range("A3").Value = 42
```

Because `Sheet1` has a *code name* string that returns `Sheet1`. Note that this identifier isn't necessarily the sheet's *name* (it is *by default* though), which the user can change at any time without accessing the Visual Basic Editor.

So if you rename the "Sheet1" tab/sheet to "Summary", but don't change its *code name*, then it will still be `Sheet1` in code - so these two instructions do exactly the same thing:

```
Sheet1.Range("A3").Value = 42
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("A3").Value = 42
```

Now, if you want an object variable holding a reference to a worksheet that exists at compile-time, *you already have one* - `Sheet1` is exactly that.

If you added a worksheet a run-time (doesn't exist at compile-time), then there's no such project-scope object variable for that sheet; that's when you need to declare your own, and assign it with the `Set` keyword:

```
Dim someSheet As Worksheet
Set someSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
```

---

#### ActiveSheet

The Excel object model also has the `ActiveSheet` object, which returns whatever sheet is currently active.

```
Sheet1.Range("A3").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Value
```

Notice the explicit qualifiers. If it's written in a standard module (.bas), this code is equivalent:

```
Sheet1.Range("A3").Value = Range("A3").Value
```

If it's written in the code-behind of a specific worksheet module, then the above code will instead be doing this:

```
Sheet1.Range("A3").Value = Me.Range("A3").Value
```

Where `Me` is whatever the specific worksheet module you're in is, so if you're writing that code in a worksheet module, you will want to explicitly qualify the `Range` member call with the `ActiveSheet` object.

---

#### Worksheet Events

If you need to execute code when a worksheet is activated, you can handle the `SheetActivate` event in the `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    If TypeOf Sh Is Worksheet Then 
        Set sheet = Sh
    Else
        'Sh is not a worksheet. could be a chart sheet, or something else.
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Debug.Print sheet.Name & " activated!"

End Sub
```

If you need to handle the `Activated` event of a specific worksheet that exists at compile-time, you need an event handler for it in that worksheet's code-behind:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Debug.Print Me.Name & " activated!"
End Sub
```

If you need to handle that event for a worksheet that is created at run-time, you need a `WithEvents` object variable in a *class module* (.cls):

```
Private WithEvents MySheet As Worksheet
```

And then you can write a handler for `MySheet_Activate` in that module, but that's more advanced stuff and I'm barely scratching the surface here, but that should get you going :)

Comment: `If Sh Is Worksheet Then` this really looks like Python syntax now. :)

Comment: `? ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1) Is Worksheet` in Immediate window produces `Run-time error '424': Object required`. So I don't think `Is` could be used this way...

Comment: You must've meant [`If TypeOf Sh Is Worksheet`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684693/how-to-check-type-of-object-in-vb-6-is-there-any-method-other-than-typename).

Answer (score 1):

`With ActiveSheet` as mentioned in the comments is really the best solution.

---

However, if you want to do it "your way", write these `Activate` events in every worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    lastWS = Me.Name
End Sub
```

Then `lastWs` would be the name of the ActiveSheet. And you would be able to refer to it like this `Worksheets(lastWs)`. Thus:

`Sheet1.Range("A3").Value = Worksheets(lastWs).Range("A3").Value`